# Available choices for Platform independent binaries/Representations

Tags: cross-platform

What are the different options available in choosing platform independent binaries or representations. I am aware of the following choices, WebAssembly, LLVM IR with JIT/AOT and Java virtual Machine. Are there any other reasonable or popular options?

What are the different tradeoffs involved, when I am using these different languages.

I am interested in backward compatibility, performance, code density and open source nature of the project.

Comment: You could use python : largely available (better adopt python3 for future as python2 may not be supported in some time).

Comment: @PtitXav Isn't python too slow? I am looking something with minimum speed compromise.

Comment: You can use PyPy interpreter to go faster but it depends if you are doing just small script or program with loops (doing same code multiple time is where you get better PyPy performance)